# Android import file

Tags: android, file-io

I know there are a couple of threads on this but none seem to fit my needs. I want to have my application import a simple text file but the name of the file and the location on the device won't always be the same. For that reason I can't do something like:

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getAssets().open("file.txt");
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new Reader(inputStream));
```

So I would need a file explorer. After looking through the API I don't know if there is a simple way to do this or if I would need to make a file chooser myself. If anyone could suggest a way to do this I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("text/plain");
startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

this will return the path of the file you selected.

Comment: This would work but it seems like it opens Google Drive to get a file instead of accessing the devices directory